# Google Slides; animate an image between paragraphs?

Tags: google-slides

I have a text box that has text, that's split into multiple paragraphs; I can easily animate each one to fade in on click by selecting the text box and adding an Object Animation of Fade In and checking 'by paragraph'. However, I need to show another element (an image) between the first and second paragraphs fading in, and I can't see a method of doing that easily.

I have 'hacked' it by making two separate text boxes; one that contains all pre-image text and one that contains all post-image text, and animate in the image between the two text box animations. But that's an awful, awful hack because I needed to manually re-style (can't copy styles apparently...) the second text box to match the first.

I doubt there's any built-in way to do this, so is there any magical plugin that'll help?